# Getting the error code message in twitter api request (java)

Tags: java, json, api, twitter

I'm trying to use twitter api in the following way:

```
String urlAdd = "https://api.twitter.com/1/following/ids.json?user_id=1000123";
URL url = new URL(urlAdd);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
```

getInputStream input stream throws IOException, it happens because i've reached my request limit. 
 I want to be able to distinghuish between request limit error and other errors. Twitter returns error message in json format, but i can't read it because of the thrown exception.

Any ideas on how can I fetch the error message?

Comment: [JSON](http://www.json.org/java/) have implementation in Java is well. Assuming you can get the JSON from the IOException, you can parse it using a JSON parser and read the error message.
On the other hand you can use one of the [Java APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#java) for Twitter.

Comment: @skwee IOException returns java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL, that is not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it:

```
String urlAdd = "https://api.twitter.com/1/following/ids.json?user_id=1000123";
URL url = new URL(urlAdd);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)urlConnection;
InputStream is;
if (httpConn.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
    is = httpConn.getErrorStream();
} else {
    is = httpConn.getInputStream();
}
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```